# unable to read data from firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i trying to read data in firestore using json the type Map must implements iterable

```
Stream<List<RentModel>> readData(){
    var json = collection.document("rent").snapshots();
    List<RentModel> rentModel = List();
    return json.map((document) {
      for (var index in document.data){     // error is here in document.data that: the type Map<String, dynamic> must implements iterable 
        rentModel.add(RentModel.fromJson(index));
      }
      return rentModel;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `for...in`, then you need to have a class that implements an `iterable` such as `List` and `Set`, but `document.data` is of type `Map`.

If you want to iterate inside a `map`, then you can use `forEach`:

```
document.data.forEach((key,values) {
  print(key);
});
```

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.3.1/dart-core/Map/forEach.html